# onChange function not behaving as expected when it receives event

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a onChange function to a presentational form component but for some reason, the onChange is not updating the object. When I log the state after setting it in onChange I only get the first character which changes when I press any character.

```js
  changeUser(event) {

    const field = event.target.name;
    const user = this.state.user;
    user[field] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      user
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.user);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Render the component.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm
        onSubmit={this.processForm}
        onChange={this.changeUser}
        errors={this.state.errors}
        successMessage={this.state.successMessage}
        user={this.state.user}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: I changed from using PureComponent to Component and the components started working perfectly. For some reason render wasnt being called on the setState.. Someone care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is assign a value to the input with `value={this.state.value}`. Here's an example:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'Please enter your username.'
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    // here's where you can pass the full value somewhere
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was logged in: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed from using PureComponent to Component and the components started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was expecting a re-render on state change with a component extended from PureComponent. The state is not compared the same way as a regular Component and thus render was not being called. forceUpdate() can help with that.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent